# Populate values in a dataframe based on matching row and column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, populate

I have two data-frames and I want to populate new column values in data-frame1 based on matching Zipcode and date from another data-frame2. 
The sample input and desired output are given below. The date formats are not the same. Dataframe 1 has more than 100k records and data-frame2 has columns for every month.

[image]

Any suggestions would be of great help since I am a newbie to python.

Comment: [Please dont paste images when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) , rather post as text so people can copy and paste in their system

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `pd.merge`. Here is an example which shows how you can use it.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                'y': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    'y': ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']})

pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='x1', right_on='x2')
```